# Continuously update position of div with click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom

I am trying to continuously get the position of a div on screen and update the new position each time a "click" event listener is clicked. At the moment my code works but feels redundant and could be simplified into a single function to move the div around the screen.

Any suggestions on how to approach this issue?

```js
// Init .innerHTML for circle
let startText = document.querySelector('.circle').innerHTML = "click";
let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

var x = 0;
let titleContainer = document.querySelector('.circle');
let progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
let avatar = document.querySelector('.avatar');
let avatarSize = document.querySelector('.avatar').clientWidth;
let totalLevels = 5;

// Listen for events
circle.addEventListener('click', mainClickMaze);

// Start position of smaller circle on progressContainer
function moveAvatarForward() {
  let progressContainerWidth = progressContainer.clientWidth;
  let sum = Math.round(progressContainerWidth / totalLevels);
  console.log(sum);

  requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  let pos = 0;

  function frame() {
    if (pos != sum) {
      pos++;
      avatar.style.marginLeft = pos + "px";
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
  }
}

// Move the avatar based on its previous location
function locationOfAvatar() {
  let pos = avatar.style.marginLeft;
  // Remove "px" from pos
  pos = pos.substring(0, pos.length - 2);
  pos = parseInt(pos);

  let progressContainerWidth = progressContainer.clientWidth;
  let sum = Math.round(progressContainerWidth / totalLevels);
  let movePos = pos + sum;
  console.log(movePos);
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  function frame() {
    if (pos != movePos) {
      pos++;
      avatar.style.marginLeft = pos + "px";
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
  }
}


// Avatar gets moved to the end of the continer
function endOfAvatar() {
  let pos = avatar.style.marginLeft;
  pos = pos.substring(0, pos.length - 2);
  pos = parseInt(pos);

 // Get size of small circle in progressContainer so that avatarSize does not exceed the bounds of progressContainer
let avatarSize = document.querySelector('.avatar').clientWidth;

let progressContainerWidth = progressContainer.clientWidth;

let sum = progressContainerWidth - avatarSize;
  console.log(sum);

  requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  function frame() {
    if (pos != sum) {
      pos++;
      avatar.style.marginLeft = pos + "px";
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
  }
}



let click = 0;

function mainClickMaze(event) {
  titleContainer.innerHTML = ++click;
  console.log('click:', click)
  if (click == 1) {
    progressContainer.style.display = 'flex';
  } else if (click == 2) {
    moveAvatarForward();
  } else if (click == 3) {
    locationOfAvatar();
  } else if (click == 4) {
    locationOfAvatar();
  } else if (click == totalLevels) {
    // Remove event listener 
    circle.removeEventListener('click', mainClickMaze);
    titleContainer.innerHTML = 'Disabled';
    endOfAvatar();
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 33.3vh;
  margin-bottom: 33.3vh;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.move-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: none;
}

.move-back {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10vw;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.move-forward {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10vw;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.progress-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 5vh;
}

.avatar {
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vw;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="move-container">
      <div class="move-back user-click">Back</div>
      <div class="move-forward user-click">Forward</div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly here is a jsfiddle for easier reference: [Update position of div](http://jsfiddle.net/wh4nac91/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simplifying the functions into one

Yes the three functions can be combined into one. To start, the `pos` variable can be simplified to default to 0 when no *left* style has been applied using [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) because `NaN` will be converted to `false`.

```
let pos = parseInt(avatar.style.marginLeft, 10) || 0;
```

Notice that the call to `parseInt()` contains two parameters:

- the *left* style of the avatar element without the `px` characters removed - this is because `parseInt()` can strip those off.
- an integer `10` - see feedback point #3 below.

Then a parameter for determining if the avatar should be moved to the end could be added, and since you are using [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like `let`, a default value can be used:

```
function moveAvatarForward(moveToEnd = false) {
```

And that value can determine the value of `movePos`

```
let movePos = pos + sum;
if (moveToEnd) {
  movePos = progressContainerWidth - avatarSize;
}
```

### Other feedback

1. Use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) whenever a variable doesn't need to be re-assigned
2. Minimize DOM lookups

   Take for example the first two variable declarations:

   > ```
   > let startText = document.querySelector('.circle').innerHTML = "click";
   > let circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
   > ```

   In this case, there are two DOM lookups for the same element. Instead of doing this, the value for `startText` could be accessed from `circle`:

   ```
   const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
   const startText = circle.innerHTML = "click";
   ```

   The same is true for `avatarSize` - it can be accessed via `avatar`. And it doesn't need to be re-declared inside `endOfAvatar()` - just remove the keyword `let`.

   Additionally, `titleContainer` points to the same thing as `startText` so those can be reduced to one variable.
3. When using `parseInt()`: "always specify a radix."<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix)</sup> (i.e. 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter - typically `10`)
4. Use prefix increment in `frame()` to increment before using a variable. Instead of the following two lines:

   > ```
   > pos++;  
   > avatar.style.marginLeft = pos + "px";
   > ```

   Just use the prefix increment to combine the lines:

   ```
   avatar.style.marginLeft = ++pos + "px";
   ```
5. Avoid poluting the global scope by wrapping the code in a function that is executed once the DOM is ready (e.g. using [`document.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event), or at least an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

#### Simplified code

The element `move-container` and its children were removed because they appear to not be used.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Init .innerHTML for circle
  const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
  circle.innerHTML = "click";
  const progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
  const avatar = document.querySelector('.avatar');
  const avatarSize = avatar.clientWidth;
  const totalLevels = 5;

  // Listen for events
  circle.addEventListener('click', mainClickMaze);

  // Move the avatar based on its previous location
  function moveAvatarForward(moveToEnd = false) {
    let pos = parseInt(avatar.style.marginLeft, 10) || 0;
    const progressContainerWidth = progressContainer.clientWidth;
    const sum = Math.round(progressContainerWidth / totalLevels);
    let movePos = pos + sum;
    if (moveToEnd) {
      movePos = progressContainerWidth - avatar.clientWidth;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);

    function frame() {
      if (pos != movePos) {
        avatar.style.marginLeft = ++pos + "px";
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
      }
    }
  }

  function mainClickMaze(event) {
    let click = parseInt(circle.innerHTML, 10) || 0;
    circle.innerHTML = ++click;
    if (click == totalLevels) {
      // Remove event listener 
      circle.removeEventListener('click', mainClickMaze);
      circle.innerHTML = 'Disabled';
    }
    if (click == 1) {
      progressContainer.style.display = 'flex';
    } else {
      moveAvatarForward(click == totalLevels);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 33.3vh;
  margin-bottom: 33.3vh;
}

.circle {
  display: flex;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 5vh;
}

.avatar {
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vw;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and the thoroughness of the explanation!